# error: expected indentifier or '(' before '=' token

Tags: struct

Here's my code

```
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

typedef struct list_head list;
typedef struct student *ptr;
typedef struct student *studentDemo;

static LIST_HEAD(student_list);

struct student{
    int studentNumber;
    int courseCredit;
    float grade;

    studentDemo = kmalloc(sizeof(*studentDemp), GFP_KERNEL);
    studentDemo -> studentNumber = 760120495;
    studentDemo -> courseCredit = 3;
    studentDemo -> grade = 3.0;
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&studentDemo->list);

}
```

[I keep getting these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db0DV.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not link to code, instead add it using the code option in your text editor. I would recommend reading [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help with your question formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few problems:

1. `typedef` declaration is not creating a memory, therefore you can't assign something to a "typedef" string. `typedef struct student * studentDemo` - can be read "whenever the compiler will encoutner the string "studentDemo", replace with a pointer to a struct of type student". Obviously you can't assign anything to such a definition.
2. You can't assign memory to a pointer during the definition of the class/struct - this should be done during `main` where memory can be allocated from the stack.

You should first declare a member of type `studentDemo` (actually the pointer to the student struct) and then you can assign to it.

You should assign the memory during `main()`.

Here is an example of C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student *studentDemo;

struct student
{
    studentDemo myStruct;
};

void main()
{
    struct student my_variable;
    my_variable.myStruct = (studentDemo)malloc(1 * sizeof(studentDemo));
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
typedef struct student *studentDemo;
```

you defined `studentDemo` as an alias-name for type `(struct student *)`
and here:

```
XXXX -> studentNumber
```

XXXX should be a pointer expression  (posibly a variable of type `struct student *`), but **not** the type itself.